# Cant enable wifi on asus

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Today I installed Ubuntu ( along side windows 8.1 ) onto my laptop and when the computer starts up. I notice that I cannot click on the Enable Wifi. I also went into network settings and tried to turn on Wifi there but it still didn't work. It would automatically turn itself back off the results from the rfkill list are as follows 
    blake@blake:~$rfkill list
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no 
        Hard blocked: yes
    1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have module asus_nb_wmi loaded with `lsmod | grep asus_nb_wmi`
If it is loaded try `sudo modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi`

```
sudo modprobe asus_nb_wmi wapf=4
```

and see if wifi can be enabled using the keyboard combo FN+F(?)
If it does work you make make it persistant with`echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf`

This solution was proposed by a kernel developer on ubuntuforums